# Laravel multiple inserts prevent

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.2. I allow the registered users to enter a date via url like
http://example.com/add_event/2014-12-12 via AJAX using GET method. what if the user uses a loop and enters infinite rows in the table. The dates are stored for the user in a table. Is there some way to detect such inputs? CSRF wont help here. How can I limit a user from inserting too many rows?

Comment: presumably they'd have a login/session. just count how many insert calls they've made and cut them off at some point.

Comment: yes that would be the last option,but i'm guessing there has to be some better way. Like laravel has a throttled method to detect number of attempts at login.

Comment: technically you shouldn't be using a GET request for this sort of thing anyways. GET requests should be idempotent.

Comment: A POST method wouldn't help either. There is no way we can avoid that.

Comment: no, post won't help fix this problem, but will prevent other problems, like link-prefetching on a webpage causing this url to get hit and register a false event.

Comment: Laravel doesn't have anything built in for this. I agree with **@Marc B**. First make it a `POST` (the RESTful way), filter it so that only logged in users can use it and at last, use the session to know the insert count per minute/hour and reject calls when a threshold is reached. That's what I'd do :)